# Error C3861: 'aligned': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, identifier

c code:

```
typedef uint16_t            WORD_UA     __attribute__((aligned(1)));    // 2 bytes
```

I am using visual studio 2015. Any way to resolve this issue? Maybe using different code? I also tried this: __declspec((aligned(1))) however, I got 'aligned' unidentified extended attribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aligned` is not a standard attribute - although it is supported by gcc.

You might be better off with the standard (C++11) `alignas` specifier. See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas.

Answer (score 0):

`__attribute__` is a gcc keyword, not Visual C++. For MSVC, this code should probably look as follows:

```
typedef __declspec(align(32)) uint16_t  WORD_UA
```